# Connect to the remote db [mysql] via spring boot strangely not working

Tags: mysql, database, spring, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I have a spring boot application which normally use local mysql db. But once I have create on my own raspberry-pi server a mysql server with mysql db. So then I have created a PuttY connection to create a tunnel.

**What I did before - so you don't have to suggest that option to me:**

- **I have extend max packages size**
- **I have granted my user with more    privileges**
- **Reseted many times teh server**

Ass you can see I have connected:
[image]
Moreover, when I'd like to connect do that db via Intelij, in database tabb, I also can: 
[image]

But when I try to connect via application - through running the app, I got errors like that:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) [spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) [spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at com.carwash.MyjniaInzynierApplication.main(MyjniaInzynierApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na] 

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
... 64 common frames omitted
```

My connection in app properties looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spring.datasource.url property you need to specify the database name.

After further troubleshooting with @bielas we realized the problem was with his tunnel configuration.

Comment: When you connect through intellij what port do you use?

Comment: That port which set while creating a tunnel - 9090

Comment: The fact that you can connect through Intellij through the tunnel means that your firewall and sql server setup is properly configured. Can you try a basic sql connection test: Example 6.1 in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: I'm using spring boot, why should I have to use that way of configuration?

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to change to that way, I'm just saying to try a basic jdbc test in order to troubleshot.

Comment: `Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.` -> But I did it once

Comment: There are 2 example. Follow the first part. You need to register the driver first.

Comment: I did it, sorry for last post. Now it about max packages, which I check now and it is  524288000 with sql query SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;

Comment: Lets try the jdbc test. Did you run it?

Comment: Yes I run it, it shows fails with max_allowed_packet wich now I have 512 M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137294/discussion-between-artemisian-and-bielas).

Comment: Are you available to help me with connecting to the remote db from deployed `SpringBoot` app on the server? This case is diffrent than above  - the `db` and app are at the same server but it couldn't connect each other

Comment: Sure thing, open a chat and post the details.

Comment: Unfortunetly I'm not allowed to create it yet. Would you be so kind and create it?

Comment: let's use the same chat room we used before: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137294/discussion-between-artemisian-and-bielas

Comment: Unfortunetly its frozen..;/

Comment: I'm at work and cannot create a chat room since there are firewall rules in place for that. 2 options: post the question or wait till I get home a find a chance, that should be within 8-9 hours

Comment: I have posted a question - please have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898529/server-side-forclose-me-to-connect-with-remote-database

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">12059600</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mysql3000.mochahost.com:3306/chamsoft_louai</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">chamsoft_louai</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
</session-factory>
```

This is my configuration file sir its good. I think that you have a bind adress to `my.ini`