# Server side forclose me to connect with remote database

Tags: mysql, database, spring, raspberry-pi

I have created `SpringBoot` application which connectes to the remote database `mysql`. I test it with two remote db connection: one has a dynamic IP, the second one has a permanent IP - it's a hosting.

**Running locally:**

When I try to run application locally (connection to DB with permanent IP), straightforward from `Intellij` everything works properly - in my browser I can see the application.

When I try to run the application with dynamic IP - I need to provide the host name instead of IP, the application throws:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'HomeGateway' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

**Running on server:**
When I try to run it on server eventhough I provide the connection to the host with dynamic IP or with pernament IP it also throws:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The `application.properties` file looks like - the connection with database with dynamic IP:

```
# REMOTE DATABASE
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://modraszka.sth.sth:3336/test3?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

**I must add that when the appication has been deployed at server, at the same server is located database - this one which has dynamic server - modraszka.sth.sth.**

Summary:
Whenever I want to run the application from server which has connection to remote DB it always throws fails even when I want to connect to the DB which is located on the same server as my application. I also tried to run application with db properites connection as: localhost:3306/test3 -> **but it also failed.**

Comment: check this post: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Comment: @artemisian unfortunately it doesn't help :(